# How to create Azure pipeline to pull github repo in Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have github repo and a azure virtual machine. I have cloned that repo in VM.

So I wanted to created a pipeline where changes in master branch of repo will be pulled on VM. Git pull task should be done by pipeline.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yet to try on latest suggestion you have provided. but I think I will work.

Comment: thanks for your trust.  You could try it . If it could work, you may consider accepting it as answer. This will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Ac9293. Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use Azure Pipeline to pull changes on your VM, you could create a [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) on your VM. Then you could directly run your pipeline on the Self-hosted agent.

In Azure Pipeline, you could run the following command(use PowerShell task, Commnad Line task or Bash task) to pull the changes from Github to your local machine.

```
cd yourfilepath\mvcexam

git checkout master

git pull origin master
```

At the same time, you could set the  [CI triggers for Github](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) in Pipeline.

In this case, when the changes are committed to Github master branch, the pipeline will be triggered  automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. with self hosted agent it will work but I want to keep agent and my vm different. I have tried Prerequisites section in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops but not working..getting connection error on pssession.

Comment: Glad to know that self-hosted agent could work . Could you please  explain the meaning of this: keep agent and my vm different.?

Comment: two different VMs one is agent and one is my vm where we pull git repo

Comment: or I can work with azure provided agent too.

Comment: @Ac9293. If you want to use the PowerShell on Target Machines task, you need to create self-signed certificate and install it in the agent you run.  Or you could use Azure Powershell task to run the following script: [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-5.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.6.1) If you use the Azure Powershell task, the script need to saved on the Azure Vm and you could set the path in the script.

Comment: Azure CLI task can also run the script. Please refer this ticket: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command and this blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-run-scripts-in-your-azure-vm-by-using-run-command/ba-p/1362360 You can also try to directly run the command in azure cli script